# How does the assignment part work in the following line of code in Angular2?

Tags: dictionary, angular, key, rxjs

I am learning from the project angular2-rxjs-chat application ong github. In the code [here](https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat/blob/master/app/ts/services/ThreadsService.ts) there is a line of code given below:

```
threads[message.thread.id] = threads[message.thread.id] ||
        message.thread;
```

where threads has earlier been defined on line 29 in the code as shown below:

```
let threads: {[key: string]: Thread} = {};
```

The comments in the code states that "store the message's thread in our acuuculator 'threads'. I need a little bit explanation of how does the assignment works on line 31 as on both sides of the assignment operator we have the same thing i.e., threads[message.thread.id]. If the statement on line 31 was like

```
(threads[message.thread.id] = message.thread;)
```

then I would explain it as a value is being assigned to a key in the map "threads". But I don't understand the full line.

Answer (score 0):

This means if `threads[message.thread.id]` already has a value then keep it, otherwise set the value to `meassage.thread`.

If the part before `||` evaluates to a value that is truthy (not `null`, `undefined`, `false`, ...)`then the part after`||`is not evaluated and the result from the part before`||`is returned otherwise the result from the expression after`||` is returned.

You could also write it as

```
if(!threads[message.thread.id]) {
  threads[message.thread.id] = message.thread;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. I already understand what you have explained so far in your three paragraphs. Please explain this part.

Comment: But in case when the object already does not exist we retain the already existing value but the code assigns a key to a key instead of assigning a value  to a key. threads[message.thread.id] = threads[message.thread.id]; On both sides of the assignment operator we have key. How can the same piece of code represent key on the left hand side of the assignment operator while the same piece of code represents a value attached to that key on the right hand side of the assignment operator?

Comment: If it already exists, then the value is just assigned to itself.